# PHP function on array only returning first value

Tags: php, arrays

I created a function to iterate through the `$_GET` array and, after verifying the data, create a constant for each element. However, it only returns the first constant.

```
function sanitize($key, $value){
    $safe_types = array(
        "month",
        "year",
        "course",
        "pagetype",
        "studentid"
    );

    if (in_array($key, $safe_types)) {
        $key = strtoupper($key);
        if (is_numeric($value) || preg_match("#^[a-z_]+#", $value)){
            define ($key, $value);
        }
    }
}

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    sanitize($key, $value);
}
```

I also tried `array_walk` with no better result.

Comment: How you are testing this? @user34682

Comment: Can you provide sample data for `$_GET`?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://eval.in/516404, so probably your `$_GET` does not have correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for taking a look and telling me it worked for you.

The issue was not the $_GET array provided but how I was testing the results. I had the following:

```
echo 
"<br/>month: ".MONTH;
"<br/>course: ".COURSE;
"<br/>pagetype: ".PAGETYPE;
"<br/>studentid: ".STUDENTID;
```

. . .but of course should have had periods instead of semicolons.